# protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter not generating screenshots in the required folder

Tags: node.js, angular, jasmine, protractor, screenshot

My protractor.conf.js has the following content. I was unable to find out whats wrong here. I have manually created target/screenshots in my root folder of angular-cli. When i run protractor conf.js the protractor tests in browser window but the screenshots aren't being generated. Can anyone help me resolve this?

```
// Protractor configuration file

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var fs = require('fs');

var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html',
  cleanDestination: false,
  showSummary: true,
  showConfiguration: false,
  reportTitle: null,
  ignoreSkippedSpecs: false,
  captureOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
  reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false
});

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  chromeOnly: true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);  
  },
  afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
  }
};
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

`protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` compatible with `jasmine2`, so change to `framework: 'jasmine2'` in your conf.js

And you need to use higher version of `Protractor` which includes `jasmine2`

I did a quick test with your conf(did little changes) and it worked.

**conf.js**

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
// var fs = require('fs');

var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
  dest: 'target/screenshots',
  filename: 'my-report.html',
  cleanDestination: false,
  showSummary: true,
  showConfiguration: false,
  reportTitle: null,
  ignoreSkippedSpecs: false,
  captureOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
  reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false
});

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
//   specs: [
//     './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
//   ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: false,
//   baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
//   chromeOnly: true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);  
  },
  afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
  }
};
```

**spec.js**

```
   describe('xxx', function(){

        it('yyy', function(){

            browser.get('https://angular.io/');
        });
    });
```

**target/screenshots** folder and **HTML** report, 
(I run for twice, so there are two screenshots.)

- click the `yyy` will open the screenshot
- `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` will create `target/screenshots` folder if not exist, no need to create in advance.
  [image]

**Version I used**:

```
protractor 5.3.0
protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter  0.5.0
```

Comment: any specific version of Protractor that can be suggested? I'm using 5.3 the latest version

Comment: Since Protractor 1.6, protractor support jasmine2, so you can use version 5.x,  like 5.3.0.  If you current protractor > 1.6, you can keep it and just  change to `framework: 'jasmine2'`, and run again.

Comment: Don't install Jasmine separately,  Protractor will install it as its dependency when Protractor being installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by adding the  'protractor-screenshoter-plugin'

```
plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-screenshoter-plugin',
    screenshotPath: <specify the path>,
    screenshotOnExpect: 'failure',
    screenshotOnSpec: 'failure+success',
    withLogs: 'true',
    writeReportFreq: 'asap',
    imageToAscii: 'failure',
    htmlReport:'true',
    verbose:'info',
    clearFoldersBeforeTest: true,
    failTestOnErrorLog: {
        failTestOnErrorLogLevel: 900
    }
},
```

Can also check https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-screenshoter-plugin