# Protractor fullpage screenshot for Angular 8

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor, automated-tests, mocha.js

I'm trying to take a screenshot of an Angular page using protractor and mocha. We've been using `protractor-screenshot-utils` as a dependency and have this on the conf.js file to override the `browser.takeScreenshot();`

```
onPrepare: function() {
    global.screenShotUtils = new screenShotUtils({
      browserInstance : browser,
      setAsDefaultScreenshotMethod : true 
    });
},
```

Unfortunately it doesn't totally override it and I'm not able to take a full page screenshot of an angular page (it's completely working on non-angular page). The screenshot that the test is getting, is what the browser can show, not including the rest of the page which boils down to my question...

Is there any other workaround to take a whole page screenshot of an Angular page using protractor + mocha?

Comment: it won't override takescreenshot method , instead creates a new function screenShotUtils() that you can call anywhere

Comment: @PDHide This line   setAsDefaultScreenshotMethod : true should actually override it based on the documentation.

Comment: Which documentation , global.function is a way of declaring a global function like take screenshot , browser etc

Comment: @PDHide https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-screenshot-utils check the bottom of the page it has a comment
//this will override default browser.takeScreenshot() method to take full page image.

Comment: At navigator are you using ?

Comment: the solution will be different from case to case. Is this an option to share a url of your application so I have the html to work with?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I'm not sure how I can send you the link. I cannot sent it here on the comment.

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov you can check the disneyland homepage. That's very similar to our app.

Comment: https://disneyland.disney.go.com/?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov yes

Answer (score 0):

It might be your navigator, if your using chrome that has a problem.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45209

You might use an hack to fix it

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(320, 2000);
```

I recommend you to have a look here, it might help : [How to take screenshot of entire page in Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406884/how-to-take-screenshot-of-entire-page-in-protractor)

Comment: This actually displays the mobile web view of our page. Not an option

Comment: Can you actually force this to be on web view?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue earlier. I had used a custom method in C# to scroll and capture the screenshot and then stitch them. I know this could be cumbersome but does the job when it's required. The logic can work something on these lines -

1. You note the height, width of the web page
2. You check the condition if the bottom of the page has reached
3. You take a screenshot and save it
4. You scroll down by the height value
5. Repeat STEP NO 2

Also, there are some 3rd party libraries you can use to resolve this.

Though I do not have the script readily available with me you can review these helpful resources - [protractor.screenshot.reporter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34668713/2923098) (*from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507364/2923098) StackOverflow answer*), [protractor-screenshot-utils](https://github.com/sudharsan-selvaraj/protractor-screenshot-utils), [takeFullPageScreenShot method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135302/2923098)

Comment: As listed on the description, I was using protractor-screenshot-utils already. Unfortunately it does not work on Angular 8.

Comment: Hey @MielYan - Can you confirm if you have tried this on - [1] Chrome with the latest version, [2] Chrome lower version (say v75), [3] Firefox? It is a possibility that the issue could be specific to a Browser + Angular 8 combination.